# SoundCloud - getDuration (callback function without button)

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Okay so i've been researching callback functions all day long but i'm still at a loss. I'm trying to have a page load and display the duration of a song on SoundCloud. I've seen plenty of examples of how to do it with a button but i'm trying to go with an automated approach. Any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <iframe id="playing" width="500" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="yes" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/66816173&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe> 
    </center>

  <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
            var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('playing'));

            widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
                console.log('Ready...');
            });

            widget.getDuration(function(duration) {alert(duration)});

        });


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving the getDuration call inside the READY callback

Comment: NICE! So solid, thank you!